# HTTP/1.1 401 SSO Redirection issue in Rally

Tags: java, rally

Am trying to update testcase results in Rally Tool by using the below code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.CreateRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.GetRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.QueryRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.CreateResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.GetResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.QueryResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.Fetch;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.QueryFilter;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.Ref;

public class RallyStatusUpdate {
  @Test
  public void f() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {


  // Create and configure a new instance of RallyRestApi
  RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI("https://rally1.rallydev.com"),"user@company.com", "123");
  restApi.setWsapiVersion("2.0.1");
  restApi.setApplicationName("Add Test Case Result");

  //Query User
  QueryRequest userRequest = new QueryRequest("user");
  userRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("user", "Subscription", "DisplayName"));
  userRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("user", "=", "user@company.com"));
  QueryResponse userQueryResponse = restApi.query(userRequest);
  JsonArray userQueryResults = userQueryResponse.getResults();
  JsonElement userQueryElement = userQueryResults.get(0);
  JsonObject userQueryObject = userQueryElement.getAsJsonObject();
  String userRef = userQueryObject.get("_ref").getAsString();

  // Query for Test Case to which we want to add results
  QueryRequest testCaseRequest = new QueryRequest("TC_001_Automation_Sample_Test");
  testCaseRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID","TC_001_Automation_Sample_Test"));
  testCaseRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=", "TC5238"));
  QueryResponse testCaseQueryResponse = restApi.query(testCaseRequest);
  JsonObject testCaseJsonObject = testCaseQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
  String testCaseRef = testCaseQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("_ref").getAsString();

  try{
      //Add a Test Case Result
      System.out.println("Creating Test Case Result...");
      JsonObject newTestCaseResult = new JsonObject();
      newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Verdict", "Pass");
      newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Date", "2015-07-16T18:00:00.000Z");
      newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Notes", "Automated Selenium Test Runs");
      newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Build", "2015.07.16.0020101");
      newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Tester", userRef);
      newTestCaseResult.addProperty("TestCase", testCaseRef);

      CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("testcaseresult", newTestCaseResult);
      CreateResponse createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest);

      if(createResponse.wasSuccessful()){
         // println(String.format("Created %s", createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString()));
          //Read Test Case
          String ref = Ref.getRelativeRef(createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString());
          System.out.println(String.format("\nReading Test Case Result %s...", ref));
          GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(ref);
          getRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Date", "Verdict"));
          GetResponse getResponse = restApi.get(getRequest);
          JsonObject obj = getResponse.getObject();
          //println(String.format("Read Test Case Result. Date = %s, Verdict = %s", obj.get("Date").getAsString(), obj.get("Verdict").getAsString()));
      } else {
          String[] createErrors;
          createErrors = createResponse.getErrors();
          System.out.println("Error occurred creating Test Case: ");
          for (int i=0; i<createErrors.length;i++) {
              System.out.println(createErrors[i]);
          }
      }

  }
  finally{
      restApi.close();
  }
  }
}
```

however I am getting "HTTP/1.1 401 SSO Redirection !" error.
As SO answers pointed 401 error maybe due to authentication issue, I changed with different logins/environment it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

If your organization uses SSO to access Rally, using an API Key is a good way to connect to CA Agile Central via the Java SDK, without the need to do the SAML handshaking. API Key details are included in this article:

http://www.ca.com/us/services-support/ca-support/ca-support-online/knowledge-base-articles.TEC01000001898.html?intcmp=searchresultclick&resultnum=2

Also, you should set your WSAPI version string to "v2.0" as there's no "2.0.1"

Comment: I changed the WSAPI version and tried to access the URL given, however it says "URL No Longer Exists", am new to rally and java would be helpful if you could guide.